# Error al descargar Fast Report en Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi

Obtengo Internal Check Error al intentar descargar Fast Report en GetIt de Delphi 10.3:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede ser la version de la IDE? Como la actualizo de ser que si..
Intente con fortes Report y obtnego el mismo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo he probado con esa versión del IDE (10.3) y me lo ha descargado e instalado sin problemas.
Vuelve a probar, no sea un problema temporal de los servidores o que desde tú estás no tengas acceso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA:** Esa instalación requiere permisos de Administrador.

Comment: Ya probe como Administrador. Aun tengo el problema. El windows puede ser de 32bit y la instalacion de Delphi tambien?

Comment: No hay forma manual de instalarlo

Comment: Segun la imagen te está dando el error al descargarlo no al instalarlo, ¿es corrrecto?
La otra  opción es que intentes descargarlo desde la web e instalarlo manualmente.

Comment: La web es esta?: https://www.fast-report.com/es/download/fast-report-vcl-6/